# How does matplotlib.pyplot.imshow 'squeeze' the data when there is not enough resolution to show all data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

When using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`, say I have a 100x100 array, but the image resolution is only 50x50, how are the data transformed or selected for plotting? What parameters control this behavior?

All I can find is in `matplotlibrc`, there is `#image.resample  : False` but I couldn't find documentation on what are the options. Does `#image.interpolation` have any impact?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There are several interpolation methods available in the library [as seen here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html). It looks like `interpolation` [is an optional parameter](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html) to the `imshow()` method.

Comment: That is useful to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I tried some tests, I think the extra data just get skipped rather than any form of transformation, at least with `interpolation='none'` and `interpolation=bilinear`. Note data points get stretched unevenly in some cases.
I don't have enough reputation to post figures, but here is the code. (The plots needs zoom in to see).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
grid = np.random.rand(10, 10)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(1,1),frameon=False)
plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
plt.axis("off")
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0,right=1,bottom=0,top=1)

plt.imshow(grid,interpolation='none',cmap='jet')

plt.savefig("test_dpi15_none.png",bbox_inches=0,pad_inches=0, dpi=15)
plt.savefig("test_dpi10_none.png",bbox_inches=0,pad_inches=0, dpi=10)
plt.savefig("test_dpi5_none.png",bbox_inches=0,pad_inches=0,dpi=5)
plt.savefig("test_dpi2_none.png",bbox_inches=0,pad_inches=0,dpi=2)
```